# How do I restore libz.so.1?

Tags: 16.04, apt, shared-library

While trying to fix an issue with Python, I accidentally blew away my `libz.so.1` binary by symlinking over it. Now a bunch of stuff, including `apt-get` won't work. The damage is limited to just libz.so.1 (which was pointing to `libz.so.1.2.8`) so I should be able to fix it by just finding the x86_64 binary and dropping it back in place, but all I can find is the source and I can't get that to compile. I'm on Xenial. Where can I find a compiled binary?

Comment: you tried, "sudo apt install --fix-missing" ?  where is this file located on HD? I can post a copy for you

Comment: Yeah, apt relies on it, so it gives me `apt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
It's in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8`

Comment: is the original file there? can you create a new symlink?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to fix this problem is to download needed package by hand, then install or extract it to the system. Of course you can perform such actions from LiveCD/LiveUSB.

How to solve such problems:

1. Visit [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/).
2. Enter missed file name in **Search the contents of packages** (in our case `libz.so.1.2.8`) specifying target *Distribution* (`xenial` in our case) and CPU *Architecture* (`amd64`):

   [image: search options]
3. Click *Search*, it will show [the results page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libz.so.1.2.8&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=amd64):

   [image: search results]
4. Then click on the [`zlib1g` link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/zlib1g)
5. In **Download** section click `amd64`:

   [image: download <code>zlib1g</code>]
6. On opened page select nearest mirror, (copy link or download deb-file by browser)

   [image: mirror]

   ```
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g_1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
   ```
7. Try to install downloaded package to the system:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i zlib1g_1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
   ```

   If it does not work - extract it directly to filesystem:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -x zlib1g_1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb /
   ```
8. And then for sure reinstall it with APT:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall zlib1g
   ```

Comment: This may need to be done from a Live CD, as `dpkg` will probably fail as well.

Comment: It is hard to broke `dpkg`, I have repaired many systems with broken `apt` with my method. `dpkg` was alive, but `apt`/`apt-get` was broken. Just tested on VM - removed *libz* with `rm`  libs, then rebooted - `dpkg` works, `apt` is broken.

Comment: Well it is easy to get a list of the libraries `dpkg` needs: `ldd /usr/bin/dpkg`. Indeed `libz` is not among them, but there are some.

Comment: Nice one, N0rbert!

Comment: Yes, `dpkg` was broken too, on my Ubuntu 18. Like all Internet connections (LAN and WiFi, `ip-config-unavailable` in  `/var/log/syslog`), archiver, and other system tools. So, I download the file according this answer via LiveCD, then unpack `deb`, copied `libz.so.1` to `/usr/local/lib` my hdd, after reboot and `dpkg -i ...` and `apt-get --reinstall ...`...

Answer (score 3):

An extension to  [N0rbert's instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036010/681688), if you are doing this in a live session, **make sure you are extracting the package to the root of your broken Ubuntu install**, as opposed to the root of the live session itself (which won't solve anything and will disappear upon restart).

From the POV of the live session, your broken install will be mounted at something like `/media/ubuntu/ae7r0-9s90s-ejf8d-d9d9f` (not actual value, but some long hash similar to that). You may have to browse to it in the file explorer to get the folder to appear.

So in the live session you'd extract using a command such as the following:

```
sudo dpkg -x zlib1g_1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb /media/ubuntu/ae7r0-9s90s-ejf8d-d9d9f/
```

Once the missing `libz.so.1` is restored to `/media/ubuntu/ae7r0-9s90s-ejf8d-d9d9f/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, you should be able to restart, run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall zlib1g` in tty1, and reboot into a working system again.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, since I blew the original file away, I couldn't `apt` or even unzip or use `rpm` or `alien`. I was able to find an RPM'd version but I couldn't get the binary out because none of the tools that rely on compression worked. So I uploaded the RPM to [Convertio](https://convertio.co/) and converted it to a tar, downloaded it and extracted it and put it back where it belongs.

Sheesh, lesson learned, be careful with those shared libs!