# FFmpeg for Super Resolution : libtensorflow_framework Relink Error & vaSyncBuffer undefined symbol

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, cuda, ffmpeg, tensorflow

I am trying to do Super Resolution with FFmpeg following this thread from Video Stackexchange : [How do the super resolution filters in FFmpeg work ?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29337/how-do-the-super-resolution-filters-in-ffmpeg-work).

**SYSTEM :**

1. Ubuntu 20.04
2. Nvidia 510 (verified using `nvidia-smi`)
3. CUDA 11.6 (verified using (`nvcc --version`)
4. CUDNN 8.4 (installation method and running verification following [their official website](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html))
5. Tensorflow 2.7.0 (installation method and running verification following [their official website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c))
6. TensorRT (installed from `pip3`)
7. Installed `zlib1g` and `zlib1g-dev` (via `apt-get`)

I had to build ffmpeg with tensorflow, here's the complete settings from the tutorial :

```
./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-gnutls \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-libtensorflow \
  --enable-nonfree
```

**ERROR :**
There was no error during building & installing FFmpeg from source. However, running FFmpeg (including `ffmpeg --version`) result in this error :

```
ffmpeg: Relink `/usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `crc32_z'
ffmpeg: symbol lookup error: ffmpeg: undefined symbol: vaSyncBuffer
```

Looks like it's tensorflow-related, however I have verified that tensorflow is working properly on my system. I could find nothing on Google, there's just one thread discussing exactly the same error ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41080)), however there is still no solution as well. I am aware the error is not symlink related, but just in case this information is needed :

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep "libtensor*"                          
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root           28 Apr 10 05:17 libtensorflow_framework.so -> libtensorflow_framework.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root           32 Apr 10 05:19 libtensorflow_framework.so.2 -> libtensorflow_framework.so.2.7.0
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root    root     38362936 Apr 10 05:14 libtensorflow_framework.so.2.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root           18 Apr 10 05:18 libtensorflow.so -> libtensorflow.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root           22 Apr 10 05:19 libtensorflow.so.2 -> libtensorflow.so.2.7.0
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root    root    784355912 Apr 10 05:14 libtensorflow.so.2.7.0

$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so.2                                                  
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdd598e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc9f93bd000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc9f926e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fc9f9264000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc9f9241000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc9f9027000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc9f900c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc9f8e18000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc9fb31a000)

$ ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep "libz.*"                                     
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Oct 15  2020 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  108936 Oct 15  2020 libz.so.1.2.11

$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1                                            
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc693bf000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3935cfb000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3935f5c000)
```

**[UPDATE]**

Error 1 is solved (see answer below). Now what remains is Error 2 :

```
$ ffmpeg --version
ffmpeg: symbol lookup error: ffmpeg: undefined symbol: vaSyncBuffer
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIX FOR ERROR 1 :**

```
ffmpeg: Relink `/usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `crc32_z'
```

I have `zlib1g` installed via `apt-get` and I guess that was the problem because it wasn't the version that FFmpeg wanted. I'm following answer from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035916/how-do-i-restore-libz-so-1) with some modifications :

1. Look for information regarding symbolic link on `libz.so.1`

   ```
   ls -ls /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep "libz*"  
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Mar 27 01:21 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11   
   116 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  116960 Mar 27 01:21 libz.so.1.2.11
   ```
2. Open [this website](http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zlib/) and look for a package following the symbolic link (mine is `libz.so.1.2.11`). I downloaded all packages (3 of them : `zlib1g`, `zlib1g-dev` and `zlib1g-dbg`).
3. Remove and purge already installed `zlib1g` and `zlib1g-dev` with `apt-get remove --purge`, then fix anything with `sudo apt --fix-broken install` if necessary.
4. Install 3 packages from point 2 with : `sudo dpkg -i`
5. `sudo ldconfig.`

Done, error 1 is gone.

**PS** : If you do `apt-get dist-upgrade` you will be asked to upgrade `zlib1g` and/or `zlib1g-dev`, well, don't upgrade them otherwise you will encounter this error again. I hold mine from upgrade with `apt-mark hold`.

**FIX FOR ERROR 2 :**

```
$ ffmpeg --version
ffmpeg: symbol lookup error: ffmpeg: undefined symbol: vaSyncBuffer
```

1. Remove all `libva*` installation from machine.
2. Install [libva](https://github.com/intel/libva) and [libva-utils](https://github.com/intel/libva-utils) from Intel Github. `libva` in particular will get installed in a directory that FFmpeg won't find. Therefore, during configuration of both, add prefix `/usr`

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr
   ```
3. Reboot.

No more vaSyncBuffer error. FFmpeg managed to find `libva`