# libavcodec: undefined symbol vaSyncBuffer

Tags: apt, compiling, ffmpeg

I just upgraded to Kubuntu 22.10, the update was successful completely minus FFmpeg.

#### Things I've tried:

- Install an older FFmpeg from Ubuntu sources
- Install master FFmpeg from source
- Install FFmpeg 5.1.2 from source
- Install FFmpeg 5.0.1 from source
- Install older libav stuff from Ubuntu sources
- Reinstall current FFmpeg from Ubuntu sources
- Reinstall `libva2` from Ubuntu sources
- Reinstall `libva2` and `libva-utils` from GitHub (as per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1402254))

This always results in the same thing: 
`ffmpeg: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.59: undefined symbol: vaSyncBuffer` 
It seems as if some other dependency of FFmpeg is calling libavcodec59 and is having issues with it

#### Things I cannot do:

- Uninstall `libva2`, as it will uninstall my desktop environment
- Revert to an `libva2=2.14.0-1`, same dependency issue with my DE

From what I have gathered, this appears to be an issue with libva, some dependency from FFmpeg requires libva>=2.16, but the Ubuntu sources don't have that version yet and that dependency doesn't state that requirement

I do have some amdgpu drivers installed, so let me know if you need to know more about them.

#### Update

I did some more searching, and this is the output from `vainfo`:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.8.0
libva info: Trying to open /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: Trying to open /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

So I'll be researching more into the amdgpu drivers, as I've had issues with those before

#### Versions:

```
Ubuntu - 22.10 Kinetic Kudu (Kubuntu)
kernel - 5.19.0-23-generic
libva2 - 2.15.0-1 (Ubuntu source)
FFmpeg - 5.1.1-1ubuntu1 (irrelevant in this case)
```

```
libva2 - 2.16 (GitHub, possible installation failure)
FFmpeg - 5.1.2 (git, no change)
FFmpeg - 5.0.2 (git, no change)
FFmpeg - 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 (Ubuntu sources, no change)
```

Reinstalling the various `libav` stuff from where ever did not change anything either

Comment: Try reinstalling `libavcodec59` maybe?

Comment: Nope, it appears to be an issue with libva or something. Perhaps I have an old version that's just not in the Ubuntu archives yet

Answer (score 0):

#### NOTICE

Unless your output to `vainfo` reads like:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.8.0
libva info: Trying to open /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: Trying to open /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

where libva is trying to load **intel** drivers from the **amdgpu** drivers location, this solution may not work for you. I repeat, I only discovered this solution because the parts that are `/opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` should instead read `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` or `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

#### Solution

Uninstall literally everything amdgpu. Drivers, core, mesa, va, dkms, everything.

I would prefer to use my GPU to encode video in x265, but the resulting file sizes are enormous compared to using the CPU, so I don't need amdgpu drivers. Let alone that my fps drops from  60 to 5 with amdgpu installed